# How to translate words literally?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, character, translate

I want to translate the names of the businesses literally.

i.e :

**FLAFEL ADAM** I want to translate it to Hebrew,

```
F -> פ
L -> ל
A -> א
.
.
.
```

so it will be **פלאפל אדם**

both names have the same spelling ! I don't care a bout the meaning , I just want to have the same spelling in both languages !

How to do that ?

Comment: It’s transliteration or transcription, not translation. There is a huge number of systems for it, and many unsystematic ways. It’s really not a programming question. After you have decided which system to use, the programming is usually straightforward (though not always).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela thank you, which system do you recommend ?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela maybe the order of the unicode characters help me doing transcription !

Answer (score 0):

You could use table lookup, i.e. a table that translates every character from one language to another. In Obj-C, you could use a `NSDictionary` that you could initialize as

```
NSDictionary *table = @{@"F": @"פ",
                       @"L": @"ל",
                       @"A": @"א"
                       };
```

etc.
You can then do the translation e.g. as

```
NSString *translatedL = table[@"L"];
```

etc.

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem that I don't have this dictionary! I just give an example !

Comment: Well, I assumed you want to use a programming language. The example I gave can easily be translated in most programming languages. If you don't want to program it, I don't have an answer